# Popover not visible inside div with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to show a popover inside a div container,but it was getting hidden inside the div because of `overflow-x : hidden`.

Here is my implementation :[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qxykryxr/)

Please help me guys.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix it by adding a couple of parameters to the [popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers):

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ html : true, container: 'body'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open popover in bottom using `data-placement="bottom"` like this

```
<a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Some content">Hover over me</a>
```

**OR**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({container: 'body'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks @kapil but my requirement is to pop right side only.

Answer (score 0):

Use `data-placement="bottom"` in achor tag

```
<a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" 
data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover" 
data-content="Some content">Hover over me</a>
```

Copied from your jsFiddle